# IIS and Glassfish

Tags: iis, web-applications, glassfish, vps

I hava a VPS running Windows Server 2008 and I have a web application deployed in Glassfish 4. How can I make glassfish listen to port 80, I know it has something related with IIS and I am not familiar with it please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS installed (which is not by default on Win 2008), it is probably using the port 80 for its default web site. Stop it, or change the port is working on.

Comment: I came by default, there is any way I can stop it and use just glassfish ?

Comment: You can open IIS console and stop the default web site. Or you can open the Windows Services console and disable IIS. Or you can uninstall IIS.